# Different behaviour of @Override in OnPreferenceChangeListener.onPreferenceChange method of Android 2.2 application depending on source code level

Tags: java, android

I'm developing Android 2.2 application and I'm going to use *Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener* interface.

I've added the following piece of code to my preference activity:

```
Preference somePref = findPreference(SOME_PREF);
    somePref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                        Object newValue) {
                    // some code here
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

If I use 1.6 Java compiler with 1.6 source code level, then everything is perfectly fine. But if I change the level of source code to 1.5 then I've got an error message:

> The method onPreferenceChange(Preference, Object) of type new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener(){} must override a superclass method

The question is: why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in Java 6 `@Override` annotations could be applied to implementation of interface methods and methods overriding method from super class. In Java 5 at the other hand `@Override` can only be applied to overriding methods.